# Multiple Format Conditions with Conditional Formatting

Tags: libreoffice, conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

I have conditional formatting applied to a column in LibreOffice Calc. There are two conditions. The first bolds the text and the second sets the background color. If the first condition is true the text is bolded, but even if the second condition is true, the second formatting doesn't happen. This works in Excel but doesn't seem to in Calc. Does Calc stop with the first condition and not allow multiple formats?

Comment: Perhaps [**this discussion**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/can-conditional-formatting-also-apply-multiple-styles-pertaining-to-different-aspects-of-a-cell-background-vs-font/86052/7?u=johnsun) will help you understand how to implement a solution to your problem (and yes - Calc is not Excel, the discussion also tells what trick MS uses to implement it, [**penultimate post from @mikekaganski**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/can-conditional-formatting-also-apply-multiple-styles-pertaining-to-different-aspects-of-a-cell-background-vs-font/86052/14?u=johnsun))